# Overriding Spartacus refreshToken method

Tags: spartacus-storefront

In my Spartacus application(version 1.4.3) , I want to avoid a http post call made from  **refreshToken** method in **user-authentication-token.service.ts** as we are having a separate setup for user login.

So I need to override the **refreshToken** method to avoid the http post method happening inside that method. Please let me know if there is a way to do it .

Answer (score 1):

You described the solution in the question.
Create your own `UserAuthenticationTokenService` which extends spartacus one. Then override `refreshToken` method and provide your service as `UserAuthenticationTokenService` (eg. `{ provide: UserAuthenticationTokenService, useClass: NewUserAuthenticationTokenService }`)

Comment: Thanks Marcin. UserAuthenticationTokenService is not exposed and when I referred https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/4743 , import { ɵn as UserAuthenticationTokenService } from '@spartacus/core'; works . But  while extending I am getting error Type '<T>(winRef: WindowRef, config?: StateConfig) => MetaReducer<T, Action>' is not a constructor function type

Comment: This doesn't look like the issue with extending it from by the alias. Looks more like issue with the class implementation. Could you provide the implementation here?

Comment: I have used import { ɵn as UserAuthenticationTokenService } from '@spartacus/core'; as mentioned in https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/4743

Comment: The extended class looks ok. Only thing that might cause problem is the return of `null` value from this method. That might be worth to check.
However the error you are getting is I think related to `getStorageSyncReducer`. I'm not exactly sure if you have done any changes to it, but I would look into `storageSync` configurations or anything else related to this reducer in your project.

Comment: Removed the null value but still getting the same error. We have not done any changes related to getStorageSyncReducer and storageSync  in my project.

Comment: If you would extend any other class from spartacus this error `not a constructor function type` does not occur? Only with the extended `UserAuthenticationTokenService`?

Comment: we have extended many other classes from spartacus without this issue. As I verified, this error message is coming only for the  below classes ClientAuthenticationTokenService,
  ClientErrorHandlingService,
  UserAuthenticationTokenService,
  UserErrorHandlingService,

Comment: Hi Marcin, We are still looking for a solution to fix this issue. Could you please assist.

Comment: Responded in https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/9607